# How do I launch an activity that lives in my test-application, not in the tested application

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-activity

I have a subclass of an abstract `Activity` subclass from the application I am testing that I am trying to instantiate in my test. The subclass lives in my test-application, not in the tested application. So how do I see to it that the instrumentation's `launchActivity` finds it? How do I specify it in my manifest?

I tried to add this to the `<application>`tag in the test-application manifest:

```
    <activity android:name="com.my.company.application.dialogs.test.MockActivity2">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

com.my.company.application.dialogs.test is the actual java-path to the activity. There is something mentioned about a package path which might not be the same in the instrumentation documentation. Where do I set this and how do I set it so that the correct activity is found (but I must still have access to the other activities in my application)?